# How do I sort mpsc::Receivers between collections depending on the message in it?

Tags: collections, rust

I have a collection containing `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Message>` and want to sort them into other collections depending on the message in it.

I'm iterating into the receivers, testing if they received a message, if so I test the message nature, and depending on it, I move the receiver to another collection:

```
for receiver in receivers.iter() {
    if let Ok(msg) = receiver.try_recv() {
        match msg {
            Message::Foo => {
                // TODO remove receiver from receivers
                foos.push(receiver);
            },
            Message::Bar => {
                // TODO remove receiver from receivers
                bars.push(receiver);
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to remove `receiver` from the `receivers` collection. Since I'm borrowing it as immutable while iterating over it, I can not modify it without encountering compilation error

I have the feeling that I'm not using the right Rust tools to complete this very basic algorithm.

[image: illustration]

To illustrate my problem, imagine that I'm sorting the colored balls from collection A to collections B and C, but I can not clone the balls and I can only see the color of a ball when taking it, which destroys the color when I take the next ball.

The solution of labeling the balls from number 0 to number 6, writing down its color aside to its index and then taking the balls to put them in the good collection is inconvenient.

Comment: It seems like this would be solved by just writing `for receiver in receivers` (no `.iter()`). Does that work for you?

Comment: But what if the receiver should remain in the original collection?
I found a similar problem on the rust user forum: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/channel-receiver-is-not-peekable/5934/2

Comment: Do you mean the receiver should remain in the original collection *and* be pushed into a different one (by reference, or something)? Or do you mean some of them should remain in the original collection *instead of* being moved to a different one? If the receivers need to be shared, you can put them in an `Arc` or something and everything gets a lot easier. The tricky thing is moving *some* out but leaving some in.

Comment: I mean some of them should remain instead of being moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd combine `Vec::retain` (originally shown by @AliceRyhl, but later edited to include more complex approaches) with either the crossbeam channels, which are `Clone`, or with `Rc<Receiver>`, which is also (trivially) clonable, but incurs a miniscule run-time cost and a heap allocation. If those are unacceptable, I propose two variants:

[✓] Variant 1: Assuming the collection is a vector, iterate using indices. It's not super-elegant, but it's not *that* bad, and it gets the job done with minimum hassle and with code anyone can understand:

```
// [✓] this is the accepted variant
let mut pos = 0;
while pos < receivers.len() {
    if let Ok(msg) = receivers[pos].try_recv() {
        match msg {
            Message::Foo => foos.push(receivers.remove(pos)),
            Message::Bar => bars.push(receivers.remove(pos)),
            _ => pos += 1,
        }
    } else {
        pos += 1;
    }
}
```

Variant 2: Store receivers in `Vec<Option<Receiver>>`. Then you can easily remove a receiver without mutating the `Vec` by [taking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) it from the `Option` and leaving `None` in its place:

```
for receiver in receivers.iter_mut() {
    if receiver.is_none() {
        continue;
    }
    if let Ok(msg) = receiver.as_ref().unwrap().try_recv() {
        match msg {
            Message::Foo => foos.push(receiver.take().unwrap()),
            Message::Bar => bars.push(receiver.take().unwrap()),
        }
    }
}
```

If `None`s remaining in `receivers` are an issue, remove them with something like `receivers.retain(Option::is_some)`.

Comment: While the "take" mechanism is interesting, I do not want to keep a long array of None which could increase in size indefinitely. I prefer the other options and will think until I found the one I like the most :)

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux Keep in mind that removing the `None`s is one `receivers.retain(Option::is_some)` away. In Rust it's a good idea to occasionally forego a bit of perfectionism to get some work done. :)

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux If the order of `receivers` does not matter, you can use `swap_remove` instead of `remove` to make this solution more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain).

```
receivers.retain(|receiver| {
    if let Ok(msg) = receiver.try_recv() {
        match msg {
            Message::Foo => {
                foos.push(receiver);
            },
            Message::Bar => {
                bars.push(receiver);
            },
        }
        // By returning false, the receiver is removed.
        false
    } else {
        // By returning true, the receiver is kept.
        true
    }
});
```

---

To have the discarded items moved to some other vector, you can write your own `retain` function. The algorithm found below will return the discarded items as an iterator. There is no guarantee of the ordering they are returned in. Unfortunately it does not support moving the channels to more than one other vector.

```
pub fn retain2<T, F>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, mut f: F) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + '_
where
    F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool,
{
    let len = vec.len();
    let mut del = 0;
    {
        let v = &mut **vec;

        for i in 0..len {
            if !f(&mut v[i]) {
                del += 1;
            } else if del > 0 {
                v.swap(i - del, i);
            }
        }
    }
    vec.drain(len - del ..)
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
let iter = retain2(&mut receivers, |receiver| {
    if let Ok(msg) = receiver.try_recv() {
        match msg {
            Message::Foo => {
                // By returning false, the receiver is sent to the iterator.
                false
            },
        }
    } else {
        // By returning true, the receiver is kept in `receivers`.
        true
    }
});

// Append all of the removed iterators to this other vector.
// They are not guaranteed to be returned in the original order.
foos.extend(iter);
```

---

Alternatively, you can obtain the behavior described in the question exactly, but this cannot be done safely using the tools in the standard library.

To do this in a way that properly handles panics, we can introduce a guard type:

```
struct RetainGuard<'a, T> {
    vec: &'a mut Vec<T>,
    // How many items have been taken?
    taken: usize,
    // How many items have been inserted again?
    // This must never be larger than `taken`.
    inserted: usize,
    // The original length of the vector.
    vec_len: usize,
}
```

We can now define two helpers for this type:

```
impl<'a, T> RetainGuard<'a, T> {
    fn take(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let i = self.taken;
        if i == self.vec_len {
            return None;
        }
        self.taken += 1;
        unsafe {
            Some(std::ptr::read(&mut self.vec[i]))
        }
    }
    // Safety:
    // Must not insert more items than has already been taken.
    unsafe fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        std::ptr::write(&mut self.vec[self.inserted], val);
        self.inserted += 1;
        debug_assert!(self.inserted <= self.taken);
    }
}
```

And we can now define a destructor to properly set the length of the vector, and in the case of panics, drop the items we have yet to inspect.

```
impl<'a, T> Drop for RetainGuard<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            self.vec.set_len(self.inserted);
            // This is an empty slice unless the closure panics.
            std::ptr::drop_in_place(self.not_taken_slice());
        }
    }
}
impl<'a, T> RetainGuard<'a, T> {
    fn not_taken_slice(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        unsafe {
            let ptr = self.vec.as_mut_ptr();
            let start = ptr.add(self.taken);
            let len = self.vec_len - self.taken;
            std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(start, len)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we can use our guard to implement the following method. Note that the destructor properly sets the length of the vector before the function returns.

```
pub fn retain3<T, F>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(T) -> Option<T>,
{
    let mut guard = RetainGuard::new(vec);
    while let Some(item) = guard.take() {
        if let Some(item) = f(item) {
            unsafe {
                // SAFETY: We have called take more times than insert.
                guard.insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method, it should be rather straight-forward to implement the desired functionality. See the full code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55294861a807b78364443f2869f45375).

Comment: This blog post is somewhat relevant: [link](https://ryhl.io/blog/temporary-shared-mutation/)

Comment: I tried this and got `expected struct std::sync::mpsc::Receiver, found reference`. "Retain" gets a reference on the receiver and then can not push it to the collection, which expects  a receiver. Should I dereference it with `*`?

Comment: Ah, so you need to move the receivers somewhere else... That's more difficult. I recommend using the [`crossbeam`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam) channel instead, since its receiver can be cloned. You can then take a clone of `receiver`, and move that clone into the other collection.

Comment: By the way, I like your blog post a lot!

Comment: How is `retain2` variant supposed to work? The OP clearly wants to _move_ receivers to `foos` and `bars`, but the closure accepts `&mut Receiver`, so `foos` and `bars` will end up containing references. And what is `other_vector`? The code appears sophisticated, but doesn't seem to attempt to answer the question.

Comment: It is also not true that "this cannot be done safely using the tools in the standard library" - I have shown how to do so in variant 1 of my answer. Granted, the code is not very sophisticated, but it works correctly and efficiently, and doesn't require any unsafe.

Comment: The `retain2` example should work fine, and does indeed attempt to answer the question. You return a boolean indicating whether the channel should be removed, and once `retain2` returns, you are given an iterator containing the channels that were removed. By using `other_vector.extend` those channels are _moved_ into `other_vector`. No references are stored in either vector.

Comment: As for `retain3`, your example is quadratic time if many channels are removed due to the use of `Vec::remove`. This is the part that cannot be avoided without unsafe.

Comment: Right, I was a bit too quick with `retain2`. I updated it. It is a slight adaption of the implementation of `Vec::retain` in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Vec::drain` to move items out of a vector. This moves all of the items, but we can handle the ones to be kept by moving them into a new `Vec` temporarily.

```
fn distribute(receivers: &mut Vec<Receiver<Message>>) -> (Vec<Receiver<Message>>, Vec<Receiver<Message>>) {
    let mut foos: Vec<Receiver<Message>> = Vec::new();
    let mut bars: Vec<Receiver<Message>> = Vec::new();
    let mut go_back: Vec<Receiver<Message>> = Vec::new();
    for receiver in receivers.drain(..) {
        if let Ok(msg) = receiver.try_recv() {
            match msg {
                Message::Foo => &mut foos,
                Message::Bar => &mut bars,
                _ => &mut go_back,
            }.push(receiver);
        }
    }
    *receivers = go_back;
    (foos, bars)
}
```

Of course, this allocates and resizes a new vector every time; a slight improvement would be to swap between two vectors instead of allocating one each time. I thought the not-yet-stable `Vec::drain_filter` might be helpful but the filter can only return a `bool`, so it can't communicate where to move the item.

[Compilable version in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b12cdbf02887c83b2c4994ca498bde94)

Comment: I am looking for an in-place version to avoid this useless drain/push that in my case would affect all receivers with no message in it (which is the most frequent case).
I could implement my own function using indices of enumeration or keys of hashmap but it's too cumbersome for this very basic algorithm.